# Missing older iTunes purchased music on new MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, music

I just bought a new MacBook Air and signed into my iTunes account to get my music, but only my most recently purchased songs showed up, and a couple of other random songs.

I tried looking at my previous purchased music not on this device, to see if I could re-download it, but they wouldn't show up. But when I looked up one of the missing albums, it said "purchased" but gave me no little cloud icon to download it.

Please help.

Comment: Could you have bought it with another Apple ID?

Comment: No I bought it with the same Apple ID I signed in with, and I searched for it all on my Mac that I just bought.